# Unique number to represent a combination of 5 numbers 1-39

Tags: combinatorics

This is a related question [poker hand representation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72542/represent-a-5-card-poker-hand) and I got a great accepted answer. The problem can be reduced to a virtual 39 card deck that from what I can tell is 16 bits.

I have 5 numbers 1-39 with none repeating. I need to uniquely identity those 5 numbers with the smallest possible number and not order dependent on the 5.  I am pretty sure the number is 2^16. From the accepted answer to the link you go 01, 10, 100, ... and then start folding back.  Then use an XOR on that matrix.  I tried but I cannot figure out when / how to start folding back.

What is the matrix / array?

Answer (score 3):

This can't be encoded into 16 bits.  The number of such hands is ${39 \choose 5} = 575757$ (is that a pretty number or what?), and $\lg(575757) \approx 19.1$, so a 5-card hand be encoded into 20 bits, but it can't be encoded in 16 bits.

You can use the methods shown there ([1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/72543/755), [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/72586/755)) to construct an encoding into 20 bits.  Alternatively, if you want a coding-theory-based answer, analogous to Yuval's answer there (the accepted answer), you'll need to find a linear code of appropriate parameters.  16 bits isn't enough.  Even 20 bits won't be enough; you'll need a slightly longer encoding, as the coding-theory-based solutions are fast to compute but yield an encoding that is slightly-longer-than-optimal.

Comment: Thanks I came into 575757 coming at this from other angles also.   I would still like to get the magic number for 16 bits as in one step I just 13 rank as for one step I just use that.   I will look at the links you provide.