# Combination generator - sets of size k from n

Tags: combinatorics

unique numbers $1 - n$
combinations (sets) of size $k$
$k < n$

do not re-use an $n$ in a set [1, 1, 1] is not valid

How to generate all *unique* sets of size $k$?
[1,2,3] = [3,2,1] order does not matter

the number of sets will be ${\binom{n}{k}}$

input
$n = 4, k = 2$
output
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 4]

I have found that is often called n chose k

hard coded it looks like

```
for (i = i; i <= n - 1; i++)  
    for (j = i + 1; j <= n - 1; j++)
```

I tried coding the first solution from Yuval Filmus but it does not work for me
It returns [1,2], [1,2]
Had to adjust for 0 based arrays

```
public static void Combinations(int n, int k)
{
    bool[] A = new bool[n];
    int[] B = Enumerable.Range(1, k).ToArray();
    Generate(1, A, B, k, n);
}
public static void Generate(int l, bool[] A, int[] B, int k, int n)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", B));
    if (l == k + 1)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("l == k + 1");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!A[i])
        {
            A[i] = true;
            B[l - 1] = i + 1;
            Generate(l + 1, A, B, k, n);
            A[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a question statement showing absolutely no effort.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I can make it work if I hard code the loops for k.  I have been working on it.  It is a much harder problem than I thought it would be.  I found one article but it had a notation I could not understand.   An ugly way to is generate and sort the k and only take unique.  I want to do better but cannot figure it out.

Comment: There's a related question with a discussion of Cover's enumerative coding algorithm here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67664/prng-for-generating-numbers-with-n-set-bits-exactly/

Comment: Please clarify (with attribution) what the problem statement is, and what your approach. Please try to explain your algorithmic idea in words as well, and *ask a question*. It should also go in the title.

Comment: @Raphael I don't have an algorithmic idea.  I tried coding the solution from  Yuval Filmus but it does not work for me and don't know python.  I tried to translate that python and it does not work for me.  I don't have attribution as it is an original problem but clearly others have had this problem.    May I ask what is not clear about the problem statement?

Comment: I made an objectively correct factual statement, answering your direct question. There is _literally no question_ in your post. It is unclear what you are asking because you _literally have not asked anything_. Your (repeatedly) expressed opinion of me is inappropriate and irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

### Ordered combinations

Here is a simple recursive routine, which has access to a Boolean array $A$ of length $n$, whose initial entries have the value *false*, and to an integer array $B$ of length $k$. The routine is called with $\ell = 1$.

**Generate($\ell$):**

- If $\ell=k+1$, output $B$, and exit the current recursive call.
- Go over elements $i$ from $1$ to $n$:
- - If $A[i]$ is *false*:
- - - Set $A[i]$ to *true*.
- - - Set $B[\ell]$ to $i$.
- - - Call Generate($\ell+1$).
- - - Set $A[i]$ to *false*.

The array $B$ consists of the current tuple, and the array $A$ keeps track of which elements are currently used (this is an optimization, since the information can be gleaned from $k$).

It is possible to convert this algorithm to an iterative one, and to improve its complexity for large $k$ (in particular, for the extreme case $k=n$). Take a look at Section 7.2 of Volume 4A of Knuth's Art of Computer Programming (see [here](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/) for table of contents).

### Unordered combinations

These are somewhat simpler, since we don't need the array $A$. The recursive routine is called with $\ell=1$:

**Generate($\ell$):**

- If $\ell = k+1$, output $B$, and exit the current recursive call.
- If $\ell = 1$, set $\max$ to 0, otherwise set $\max$ to $B[\ell-1]$.
- Go over all elements $i$ from $\max+1$ to $n-(k-\ell)$:
- - Set $B[\ell]$ to $i$.
- - Call Generate($\ell+1$).

This generates unordered combinations (like you asked in the question), each of them itself ordered. In the code, $\max$ is just the maximum element in the current tuple. You can also pass it as a parameter as in bstrauch24's answer.

Again, the algorithm can be made iterative, and Knuth (same place) has even more information.

Comment: Thanks I kind of follow.  It looks like I would exit after generating the first set.  I guess I will start there.

Comment: It's a *return* statement (in C parlance). It only exits the current call. Try programming it in your favorite programming language.

Comment: I know this is not a coding site but I could not make it work.  Thanks

Comment: Need to exit with ℓ=k+1 or get an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: @Paparazzi That's what I'm doing. I changed the wording since it seemed to have been confusing.

Comment: There is no exit in the revised answer. If I don't exit I get an index out of range exception on set B[ℓ] to i.  If I only output on ℓ=k+1 I get exactly one output.

Comment: Somehow my implementation suffers from neither problem. Make sure you understand how recursion works.

Comment: Recursion is pretty simple you call yourself.   I posted code if you want to test for yourself.  Thank you for you help.  You are one on the top contributors on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution in python:

```
n, k = 4, 2

def dfs(A, start):
    if len(A) == k:
        print(A)

    for i in range(start, n + 1):
        A.append(i)
        dfs(A, i + 1)
        A.pop()

dfs([], 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know python.  I know C# and can usually figure out Java.

Comment: Perhaps you can convert your code to pseudocode? Not everybody knows what `range`, `append`, `pop` and other elements of python are.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally discouraged here, be it pseudo or real code. What is the idea? Why do you think it's correct?