# is it possible to compress a sequence of progressive unique numbers dramatically?

Tags: data-compression

Let's say I have a 60 set of numbers from **0-100,000** so like `[81, 98, 115, 189, 254, ... , 97866, 98441, 99671]` all unique and progressively increasing. Would it be mathematically possible to compress this sequence by 80-90%? so far I've tried gzip which only compresses at 50% and other algorithms the best one I found was at 0.68% almost 0.69%. Though I have not tried mixing this algorithms together to get to 80-90% but is this mathematically possible?

The current limit I am currently trying to achieve is a byte representation that is below the number of sets I have. So for example this set `[81, 98, 115, 189, 254, ... , 97866, 98441, 99671]` can be translated to something with the size of 50 bytes that is below 60 so that would do great for me

also I know of subtracting the lower value to the other value, example : [81, 98, 115] → [81, 17, 17] but this doesn't really work for what I am after.

Comment: Is there any structure to the sequences? Apart from being increasing

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Like @nirshahar says, the more information we have about the problem, the more we can compress your numbers.  For example, the sequence 5,8,13,21,34,55,89 can be compressed into 2 bytes, after finding that the numbers are all Fibonacci numbers.  I am just trying to provide a dramatic example, but there is a theory of information by Claude Shannon, and the more we have, the more we can help.

Comment: Here's one approach: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67664/prng-for-generating-numbers-with-n-set-bits-exactly/67669#67669 Also look up inverted indexes, which will give you lots of solutions for essentially the same problem.

Comment: How many numbers per set ? What is the size of the uncompressed sequence ?

Comment: You give us no clue about the distribution, so we cannot answer. At least supply a plot of the values or explain how they are generated.

Comment: Please don't use "edit:....".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters the question for the first time.  No need to mark what has changed.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Please don't add "the problem has been solved".  You can write an answer below to explain what answer you came up with, if you wish.  We are not a discussion forum, and this site works differently from others you might be used to.  Questions exist here not only for your benefit, but are intended to hopefully benefit others as well in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a counting point of view, there are $\binom{100000}{60}$ such sequences and so, numbering them, you could theoritically compress it down to $\log_2\binom{100000}{60}$ bits but not further. This is roughly equal to 90 octets.

Comment: So “60 random unique increasing numbers from 0 to 100,000” can be compressed by about 30% compared to the optimal compression of “60 random numbers from 0 to 100,000”.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Nathaniel's answer, you can number the subsets efficiently using the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system).

In short, say your subset is $[c_1, c_2,\ldots, c_k]$ (where $k=60$). Compute $N = \binom{c_1}{1}+\binom{c_2}{2}+\ldots+\binom{c_k}{k}$. (note that we use the convention that $\binom{n}{m} = 0$ for $n<m$). This number $N$ represents your subset, and you can simply store that.

Now the other way around, we want to be able to recover the subset from this number $N$. We'll start by finding the maximum value $c_k$. To do so, find the largest value of $c$ among $k-1,k,k+1\ldots$ for which $\binom{c}{k} \leq N$. This is the largest element in the subset (i.e. this is $c_k$). Now replace $N$ with $N-\binom{c_k}{k}$, then replace $k$ with $k-1$ and repeat the procedure until $k$ reaches $0$.

To make this efficient (time wise) you might want to give some thought about how you compute the binomial coefficients. Perhaps the most hassle-free approach is to compute them when needed by a recursive function with memoization (that way you can harvest some of the computation done for previous binomial coefficients when computing a new one, and don't spend too much time computing coefficients you won't end up needing).