Generating a random bitstring with at most $k$ bits set
Inspired by this SO post, I'd like to generate random bitstrings of a length $n$, having at most $k$ bits set for some $k$. Bitstrings should be selected uniformly at random amongst all possible bitstrings. (The original question also asks them to be unique, but that's easily handled with e.g. a set to catch duplicates).
Currently, I have a few approaches, none of which is ideal:

For large $k$ ($\approx n/2$), just perform rejection sampling across all bitstrings of length $k$.
For very small $k$, we can explicitly calculate the distribution of 1-bit counts via the binomial coefficients, then randomly select a target count from this distribution. (Generating bitstrings with exactly k bits set is much easier)
For general use, choose a sequence of length $n$ out of a pool of $n$ 0s and $k$ 1s. While efficient, this approach is biased in favour of 1-bit counts near $k/2$.

Is there an efficient and correct algorithm for selecting random bitstrings with up to $k$ bits set?

Partial answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67664/prng-for-generating-numbers-with-n-set-bits-exactly/67669

@Pseudonym: as noted in my question, "generating bitstrings with exactly k bits set is much easier".

Yes.  Let $f(n,k)$ denote the number of such bitstrings (i.e., number of $n$-bit strings containing $\le k$ ones).  Then it is easy to sample from this set.  In particular, use the following recursive algorithm:
Sample the first bit of such a string by choosing 1 with probability $p$ and 0 with probability $1-p$, where $p=f(n-1,k-1)/f(n,k)$.  If the first bit is 1, pick the remaining $n-1$ bits by recursively sampling from $n-1$-bit strings containing $\le k-1$ ones.  If the first bit is 0, pick the remaining $n-1$ bits by recursively sampling from $n-1$-bit strings containing $\le k$ ones.
So all that remains is to describe an algorithm to compute $f(n,k)$.  And this is easy to compute using dynamic programming, by taking advantage of the recurrence
$$f(n,k) = f(n-1,k-1) + f(n-1,k),$$
with base cases $f(n,0)=1$.

I think OP knows this algorithm (their second bullet point), but it really isn't efficient - it needs bignum arithmetic and potentially many random bits per output bit. It's better for exactly $k$ set bits, because then $p=k/n$.
